# LAMP Server Questions

Tags: server

I am hosting or at least supposed to be hosting a LAMP server website on a Pi 2B

WordPress is what I'm using to build the website.

The question is, does the server automatically activate on startup of the Pi? Or is there some process I am supposed to take to turn it back on? I was tinkering around with it a little and on the RPI.ORG website the instructions detail how to install everything.

However it doesn't go into detail about how to operate it properly to be successful. I don't have a constant need for it to be on all the time, so when i do turn on the Pi, I would hope that the server automatically activates on start up.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you installed Apache via apt-get it will restart on startup without you needing to do anything. You can verify it is running by doing the following:

```
sudo service apache2 status
```

Since you mention that you do not need it all the time you can use a similar command to start:

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

stop:

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```

and restart:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: ok. thank you very much. i knew i was close to the correct answer, but i didnt know how close. i figured i could use the command

sudo  /etc/init.d/apache2 initiate

or something like that.

would you happen to have a link on how to make the server available to the outside world using my website's URL after i'm done editing the website?

Comment: Do a search for port forwarding with your router. I would advise against this though. One because the Pi will not serve much load, secondly because you likely do not have the Pi properly secured to be exposed to the web. This would represent a huge risk not only to the Pi and its data, but the rest of your network and data as well.

Comment: the website doesnt get much traffic at all. maybe a few hits a week. im not concerned about that.

however, is there a firewall and antivirus programs that can be used on RPI? I would assume so. i just started into alot of this, so i am still figuring things out. up until this point i just used the pi to tinker with games and small stuff

Comment: @LAMPPROBS But you should be worried about your security, and there are places you can host WordPress for a few dollars a month. Is your privacy and security worth $5 a month.

Comment: that's why i asked if there's an antivirus and firewall program for pi. i would imagine so. i just havent found anything with my limited resources.

Comment: @LAMPPROBS There is antivirus and a firewall for the Pi. You may have limited resources but Google is your friend. However, you have proved my point about your security knowledge. Running a server open to the internet requires far more security and protection than antivirus and a firewall.

Comment: my security knowledge is not great. all i know is there's programs out there. like McAfee, norton, etc. i do know that theres limited stuff for raspberry pi. but let me also be clear, that i dont intend to connect the pi to the outside world until i have all possible measures in place to ensure there wont be a breach. however, afterall, even more quality computers carry the same risk as the raspberry pi as far as security issues.

Comment: @LAMPPROBS Yes, they do carry the same risks and I wouldn' suggest you put them on the net by yourself either. Ask yourself this if Target, Homedepot etc. with a full IT staff and can and do get hacked why do you think you are going to fair any better.

Comment: oh, i dont think i will fare any better lol...now heres another question...how do i change the username of the pi. ive changed the hostname, but i want to change the default username without a whole bunch of hooplah, like creating a new user and deleting the old one. i have already messed it up and had to reinstall raspbian. i am using noobs, as my netbook doesnt have room to download the raspbian image and the installers. theres so many ways, and i cant figure out the easiest way to do it.

Comment: @LAMPPROBS: *Without a bunch of hoopla*... That would be another question entirely, and I suggest you ask it as such. Server security is a big deal, and I highly suggest you read about how to harden your RPi.